# Azure Speech to Text stops working after 3 to 4 minutes in Android SDK Version 1.2.2

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-speech

We are facing issue using speech to text API, it works fine for around 4 minutes and suddenly it stops working. When checking in logcat(Android studio error logger) it shows errors as below. We are using it with subscription key

02-08 03:30:02.434 27572-4854/ I/NLPLAT: WebSocket closed unexpectedly, status: 0
02-08 03:30:02.844 27572-4865/ I/NLPLAT: Failed to 'hresult', HR=80004005, WebSocket connection failed
.....
.....
.....
02-08 03:30:11.552 27572-5155/ I/NLPLAT: Failed to 'hresult', HR=80004005, WebSocket connection failed
02-08 03:30:11.552 27572-5155/ I/NLPLAT: WebSocket closed unexpectedly, status: 0

02-08 03:29:38.057 27572-8428/ I/NLPLAT: WebSocket closed unexpectedly, status: 0
02-08 03:29:38.057 27572-8428/ I/NLPLAT: Initiating websocket connection. m_connection=0xbdf1d924 host=websockets.platform.bing.com port=443
02-08 03:29:38.060 27572-8430/ I/NLPLAT: WebSocket closed unexpectedly, status: 0
02-08 03:29:38.062 27572-8430/ I/NLPLAT: Initiating websocket connection. m_connection=0xbdf1d924 host=websockets.platform.bing.com port=443
02-08 03:29:38.065 27572-8432/ I/NLPLAT: WebSocket closed unexpectedly, status: 0

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this tutorial. I tried this and it works.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/cognitive-speech-stt-android/

The app works fine. If you have any doubts with the tutorial, I would be happy to help.