# Azure Speech to Text stops working after 3-4 minutes

Tags: c#, azure, speech-to-text

I'm attempting to transcribe audio files about 10-20 minutes in length. Azure Speech to Text stops after ~3 minutes 20 seconds. I'm using continuous recognition and I'm not sure what the issue is. The solution in this post is now a defunct link:

[Azure Speech to Text stops working after 3 to 4 minutes in Android SDK Version 1.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807388/azure-speech-to-text-stops-working-after-3-to-4-minutes-in-android-sdk-version-1)

My code is:

```
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace STTwithTime
{
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var key = "subscriptionkey";
        var region = "region";
        var audioFilePath = @"";
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(key, region);

        // Generates timestamps
        speechConfig.RequestWordLevelTimestamps();
        speechConfig.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Detailed;

        var stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

        var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(audioFilePath);
        var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

        //Display Recognized
        recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
            {
                
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(e.Result.Properties.GetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_JsonResult));
                
                var maxConfidenceValue = result.NBest.Max(item => item.Confidence);
                var maxConfidence =  result.NBest.Find(item => item.Confidence == maxConfidenceValue);
                Console.WriteLine("================================");
                Console.WriteLine("Confidence:"+maxConfidence.Confidence);
                Console.WriteLine("RECOGNIZED :" + maxConfidence.Display);
                Console.WriteLine("Duration: :" + Convert.ToDouble(result.Duration) / 10000000);
                Console.WriteLine("Words:");
                foreach (var word in maxConfidence.Words) {
                    Console.WriteLine(word.word + "=> offset:" + Convert.ToDouble(word.Offset) / 10000000 + " duration:" + Convert.ToDouble(word.Duration) / 10000000);
                }
                
            }
            else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
            }
        };

        recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={e.Reason}");

            if (e.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={e.ErrorCode}");
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={e.ErrorDetails}");
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
            }

            stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
        };

        recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n    Session stopped event.");
            stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
        };

        recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Waits for completion. Use Task.WaitAny to keep the task rooted.
        Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });

        // Keeps external console from closing too quickly
        string v = Console.ReadLine();


    }

}

public class Word
{
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public string word { get; set; }
}

public class NBest
{
    public double Confidence { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public string ITN { get; set; }
    public string Lexical { get; set; }
    public string MaskedITN { get; set; }
    public List<Word> Words { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<NBest> NBest { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public string RecognitionStatus { get; set; }
}
}
```

How do I resolve the issue? I need to transcribe the entire audio file. Are there any workarounds? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link is in Azure terms pretty outdated :-) What about this .NET Core sample? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/csharp/dotnetcore/console -> https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/681860bc03b89e607c568570f7e95b901b4fedf0/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/intent_recognition_samples.cs#L85

Comment: I wrote the above code from those examples. Still having the issue of transcriptions stopping about 200 seconds into each audio file. No errors are returned. Output log doesn't report any warnings. The integrated terminal says that some of the packages are being restored to NETFramework versions 4.6 or 4.7 depending on the package. My project was written using the net5.0 target framework.